# How to check if a key exists in a nested JSON object in node?

Tags: json, node.js

I've got the following JSON being sent to the server from the browser:

```
{
    "title": "Testing again 2",
    "abstract": "An example document",
    "_href": "http://google.com",
    "tags": [ "person" ],
    "attributes": [ {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "TEXT",
        "data": "test"
    } ],
    "sections": [ {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "LIST",
        "data": [ {
            "revision": 124,
            "text": "test"
        } ]
    } ]
}
```

I need to make sure that the keys "_href", "id" and "revision" are not in the object anyplace at any level.

I found [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112904/test-if-a-key-exists-anywhere-in-a-nested-object) but it doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

I searched npms.io and found `has-any-deep` which you can use after JSON.parse ing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but not 100% foolproof solution would be to parse the JSON to string, and just search for your keys:

```
var a = JSON.stringify(JSONObject);
var occurs = false;
['"_href"', '"id"', '"version"'].forEach(function(string) {
 if(a.indexOf(string) > -1) occurs = true;
});
```

The issue of course, is if there are values that match 
`'_href'`, `'id'`, `'version'` in your JSON. But if you want to use native JS, I guess this is a good bet.

```js
var a = {
    "title": "Testing again 2",
    "abstract": "An example document",
   
    "tags": [ "person" ],
    "attributes": [ {
        
        "type": "TEXT",
        "data": "test"
    } ],
    "sections": [ {
        
        "type": "_href asdad",
        "data": [ {
            
            "text": "test"
        } ]
    } ]
},
    
b = {
    "title": "Testing again 2",
    "abstract": "An example document",
    "_href": "http://google.com",
    "tags": [ "person" ],
    "attributes": [ {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "TEXT",
        "data": "test"
    } ],
    "sections": [ {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "LIST",
        "data": [ {
            "revision": 124,
            "text": "test"
        } ]
    } ]
},
aJson = JSON.stringify(a),
bJson = JSON.stringify(b);

var occursa = false, occursb = false;

['"_href"', '"id"', '"version"'].forEach(function(string) {
 if(aJson.indexOf(string) > -1) { occursa = true};
});

['"_href"', '"id"', '"version"'].forEach(function(string) {
 if(bJson.indexOf(string) > -1) { occursb = true};
});

console.log("a");
console.log(occursa);
console.log("b");
console.log(occursb);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse json then check into the data

```
var str = '{
    "title": "Testing again 2",
    "abstract": "An example document",
    "_href": "http://google.com",
    "tags": [ "person" ],
    "attributes": [ {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "TEXT",
        "data": "test"
    } ],
    "sections": [ {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "LIST",
        "data": [ {
            "revision": 124,
            "text": "test"
        } ]
    } ]
}';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);

if ( typeof jsonObj._href == 'undefined') {
    // check 
}
```

Comment: This will not check at deeper levels.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the optional second `reviver` parameter to `JSON.parse` for this:

```
function hasBadProp(json) {
  let badProp = false;

  JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => {
    if ([_href", "id", "revision"].includes(k)) badProp = true;
    return v;
 });

 return badProp;
}
```